# Embed the connectivity graph into the math equation

Tags: equations

I wonder if someone can tell me how to write the latex script to reproduce the following equation?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: where, please, have you see this image?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are dedicated packages for that but plain Ti*k*Z is more than sufficient to get going.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{cgraph/.style={baseline={(C.base)},
dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
x=1em,y=1em,
execute at begin picture={
    \node[circle,inner sep=0pt](C){\vphantom{A}};
    \path (-1,1) node[dot,label=above:{$1$}] (1){}
    (-1,-1) node[dot,label=below:{$2$}] (2){}
    (1,1) node[dot,label=above:{$3$}] (3){}
    (1,-1) node[dot,label=below:{$4$}] (4){};
}}}
\begin{document}
\[ \Braket{\mu_1(r_1)\,\mu_2(r_2)\,\mu_3(r_3)\,\mu_4(r_4)}
=\tikz[cgraph,x=0.5em]{\draw (1) -- (2) (3) -- (4);}
+\tikz[cgraph,y=0.5em]{\draw (1) -- (3) (2) -- (4);}
+\tikz[cgraph]{\draw (1) -- (4) (2) -- (3);}
+\tikz[cgraph]{\draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- (1);}
\]
or
\[ \Braket{\mu_1(r_1)\,\mu_2(r_2)\,\mu_3(r_3)\,\mu_4(r_4)}
=\tikz[cgraph,x=0.5em]{\draw (1) -- (2) (3) -- (4);}
+\tikz[cgraph,y=0.5em]{\draw (1) -- (3) (2) -- (4);}
+\tikz[cgraph]{\draw (1) -- (4) (2) -- (C.225) arc[start angle=225,end
angle=45,radius=0.8ex] --(3);}
+\tikz[cgraph]{\draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- (1);}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent and I have upvoted instantanely.

Comment: Thank you. This is great!