# Equation graph using feyn package

Tags: feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

Starting from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595555/embed-the-connectivity-graph-into-the-math-equation) with the picture

[image]

> Is it possible with this MWE to create the connectivity graph into the math equation using `feyn` package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{feyn}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle \mu(r_1)\mu(r_2)\mu(r_3)\mu(r_4) \rangle &=&
\feyn{!{fA}{1} + !{fA}{2} + !{fA}{3} + !{fA}{4}}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `feynmp` relies on MetaPost, you could directly draw it with MetaPost itself (?)

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Hi, I have tried to put into `\feyn{...}` a generic graph (for example this `\begin{fmffile}{diagram} 
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,70) 
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{plain}{i2,v1,o2}
\fmf{plain}{i1,v2,o1}
\fmf{dashes,label=$a_0$}{v1,v3}
\fmf{dashes,label=$A_0$}{v3,v2}
\fmfdot{v1,v2}
\fmfv{decor.shape=cross,decor.size=4thick}{v3}
% labels for external lines
\fmflabel{$\gamma_5$}{v1}
\fmflabel{$\gamma_5$}{v2}
%\fmflabel{$\chi$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$q$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$q$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$\psi$}{i2}
\fmflabel{$\psi$}{o2}
\end{fmfgraph*} 
\end{fmffile}`)but it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for the picture environment! No packages needed. I have defined a command that takes as arguments the positions of the vertices and the slopes of the two lines. Because the final graph has 4 lines I made two versions of the command, one with `\begin{picture}\end{picture}` and one without - the second version allows to add more elements.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% #1 position of vertex 2
% #2 starting point of first line
% #3 slope of first line
% #4 position of vertex 1
% #5 position of vertex 4
% #6 starting point of second line
% #7 slope of second line
% #8 position of vertex 3
\newcommand{\conngraph}[8]{%
\begin{picture}(5,5)
\conngraphinner{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}
\end{picture}
}
\newcommand{\conngraphinner}[8]{%
\put(#1){\kern-2pt\raise-6pt\hbox{\tiny2}}
\put(#1){\circle*{1}}\put(#2){\line(#3){4}}\put(#4){\circle*{1}}
\put(#4){\kern-2pt\raise3pt\hbox{\tiny1}}
\put(#5){\kern-2pt\raise-6pt\hbox{\tiny4}}
\put(#5){\circle*{1}}\put(#6){\line(#7){4}}\put(#8){\circle*{1}}
\put(#8){\kern-2pt\raise3pt\hbox{\tiny3}}
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle \mu(r_1)\mu(r_2)\mu(r_3)\mu(r_4) \rangle &=&
\conngraph{0,-1}{0,-1}{0,1}{0,3}{3,-1}{3,-1}{0,1}{3,3}\enspace
\conngraph{0,0}{0,0}{1,0}{0,2}{4,0}{0,2}{1,0}{4,2} +
\conngraph{0,-1}{0,-1}{1,1}{0,3}{4,-1}{0,3}{1,-1}{4,3} +
\begin{picture}(5,5)
\conngraphinner{0,-1}{0,-1}{0,1}{0,3}{4,-1}{4,-1}{0,1}{4,3}
\put(0,3){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(0,-1){\line(1,0){4}}
\end{picture}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

<sub>Note that this is a joke answer :) I would recommend using the TikZ solution from the other question.</sub>

Comment: Very nice Marijn I have appreciated the consideration on my answer. My congratulations.